# ShellExecute - Тип данных

Tags: delphi

```
ShellExecute (Form3.Handle, nil, label1.Caption, nil, nil, SW_RESTORE);
```

Такая ошибка:

**[DCC Error] Unit3.pas(70): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TCaption' and 'PAnsiChar'**

Что делать, если адрес сайта должен хранится где-либо (label, переменная или ещё что-либо) ?

Comment: С точки зрения С++:

ShellExecute требует указателя на char. а у Вас label1.Caption - AnsiString. 

Comment: Ну, и что же так не понравилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать преобразование типов:
    PAnsiChar(Label1.Caption)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте приведение PCHAR от TCaption:

```
ShellExecute(Form3.Handle, nil, PCHAR(label1.Caption), nil, nil, SW_RESTORE);
```